# jqxWidgets cascading comboBox

Tags: jquery, jqxwidgets

Everybody
I want a help to make populate combo box using jqxwidgets.
when i choose a country from country combo-box, the cities of the selected country will be appeared in the city combo-box.
my code is:

```
<div id="country"></div>
<div id="city"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    var country = ["AUE","Egypt","Saudi Arabia" ];

    var city = ["Abu Dabi","Dubi","El Ain","Sharga",    "Alex","Cairo","Daqhlia","Giza","Gharbia","Marsa Matroh","Qaliubia", "Dammam","Jeddah","Madina","Mecca","Ryadh"];
    $("#country, #city").jqxComboBox({height: 40, dropDownHeight:'150px', theme: 'darkblue'});

   $("#country").jqxComboBox({source: country,placeHolder:"Country"});

   $("#city").jqxComboBox({source: city,placeHolder:"City"});

});
</script>
```

Comment: how can i make combo box city depend on combo box country?